# Use dict to replace column names

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, rename

I have a dataframe that I'd like to replace column names with based on a dictionary mapping

```
df = 
     A_  B_  C29  D_9
0    01  01  01   01
1    02  01  01   01 
2    03  01  01   01 
3    04  01  01   01

dict = 
    A_ : A
    B_ : B
    C29 : C
    D_9 : D
```

I've tried using replace and rename which haven't worked

```
df= df.rename(columns = dict)
df= df.replace(dict)
```

Comment: `df.rename(columns=dict)`? And don't use built-in keywords as variable names.

Comment: Your rename coded should work as long as your aren't having whitespace issues.